# External Console Application Control

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, console-application

I am trying to solve a difficult task, for part of which a console application was written several years ago. The source code of the console application has been lost and to rewrite it would most likely take several hundred hours. I have been able to use the console application by hacking it into the top level application using the following snippet:

```
solver = new Process();
solver.StartInfo.FileName = "HPTSolver.exe";
solver.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
solver.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
solver.Start();
```

I can then trigger the console application by providing the necessary input parameters via

```
solver.StandardInput.WriteLine("RunCalculation");
```

The result of the console application is saved out to a text file and in the top level application I currently wait for the file to be created before continuing:

```
while (!File.Exists("result.txt"))
    Thread.Sleep(50);
```

So finally my question is related to this final part where I wait for the results file to be created. Although my current solution works it is clearly the most naive solution. Is there a better solution to detect the creation of the result file and allow the top level application to continue? I have already tried reading the standard output of the console application but data is only output when the application closes, so thats not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using the FileSystemWatcher?

MSDN [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Hope that helps

Paul

Comment: I tested the FileSystemWatcher but it is unfortunately about 100 slower than my current solution.

Comment: Slower in what way? Is it significant? There may be a delay between the changes being made on the file system and the event being raised but I imagine that would be far less CPU intensive than sitting in a loop until the file has been written.

Comment: You could simply set up your own timer to poll the directory at your own defined interval (say 250ms) until the file is created. It really depends on your requirements and the length of the process to create the file in the first place.

Comment: I need to run the console application serveral 100K times so any additional delay in detecting the results file considerably increases the overall run time. The delay of the FileSystemWatcher was order 1 second. The console application is generally done in 40ms, hence my choice of 50ms in the poll I have already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

What about waiting for the console application to exit?

```
solver = new Process();
solver.StartInfo.FileName = "HPTSolver.exe";
solver.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
solver.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
solver.Start();

solver.WaitForExit()
```

Or you could grab the StdOut and watch for specific messages.

Comment: ^ This seems to be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: There is overhead in starting the console application. My current implementation is already faster. I already discuss the problem capturing stdout in my OP.